# syncing CloudKit and iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I have an app which currently syncs via iCloud, so the user can use the app on multiple iOS devices and has the same data everywhere.

Now I'd like to switch to CloudKit; but how is this possible if the user e.g. only updates on one device? So it's the same user, one time with CloudKit, one time still with iCloud... I guess syncing isn't possible then if I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

just check if there is data in the private container. If not, then migrate and sync the data from iCloud to CloudKit. Then if he opens the app on another device then the data is already migrated to CloudKit and you can just sync that data.

Comment: but how to handle this in the old (= already released) app version? There's only the iCloud-container which doesn't know about CloudKit, so changes won't be synced to that device, that's what I meant...

Comment: There are 3 options to solve that. The first is to force an app update. But then you already need to have a mechanism for that in your current app. 2nd is that you could keep on syncing to both iCloud and CloudKit for a short period of time. 3rd is that you give your users a warning that all updates using the old version of the app that will be made after today will be lost and that they have to upgrade all devices.